# SAS ERROR: No terminal connected to the SAS session

Tags: sas

We would like to configure a metadata libname connection by which users will enter their login credentials whenever accessing the remote database (uses MYSQL engine).

Setting the Authentication type to 'Prompt' as follows:

[image]

works fine in Base SAS:

[image]

But not in EG:

[image]

or WRS:

```
Error messages:An error occurred in processing the report element. Refresh the page to try again. Contact your administrator if this problem persists. 
[a13711980861670.7733371536680634_0_0] Error Rendering the Report
Error while submitting SAS code 
1 options Locale=en_GB; 
2 LIBNAME xxx MYSQL PRESERVE_COL_NAMES=YES DIRECT_SQL=NONE PRESERVE_TAB_NAMES=YES DBPROMPT=YES
DATABASE=xxx MYSQL_PORT=4444 SERVER="xxxx" USER=xxxx PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ; 
   3 
4 PROC SQL; 
5 Create table wrstemp.xxxx as 
6 SELECT DISTINCT 
7 table0.fxxx AS DIR_2 , 
8 ( table0.sxxx ) AS DIR_3 ,
 9 table0.sysxxx AS DIR_4 , 
10 SUM( ( ranuni(0) ) ) AS DIR_1 LABEL='DataItem1' 
11 FROM 
12 xxxx.xxx table0 
13 GROUP BY 
14 1, 
15 2, 
16 3; 
ERROR: No terminal connected to the SAS session
```

As per note [3352](http://support.sas.com/kb/3/352.html), we are not using SAS/Connect (and the autoexecs are empty)

Also, the advice in [7980](http://support.sas.com/kb/7/980.html) is not useful as we are using the mid-tier applications so no windowing available..

Comment: shoot an email to support@sas.com they can be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Web Report Studio, you can set the "Show Manage Credentials" property to "Yes" - this will allow an authentication domain and user/password to be set for the lifetime of the WRS Session.  See documentation here:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/biwaag/63149/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002938529.htm#a003287493

For Enterprise Guide, this was the response from SAS support:

*The Metadata Library engine (libname META) is not able to surface credential requests to the client. Thus, when a library is configured to use MLE, the credentials must be present in metadata in order for EG to successfully assign the library.
Setting the DBMS library to use an authdomain that has credentials stored will result in credentials being applied.
If that is not possible due to site security constraints, then setting the assignment mode to "EG Assign" so that EG builds up a libname statement instead of using the META engine should result in the prompting.  To do that either modify the library in EG to have "EG Assign" or use SMC and set an extended property of "AssignMode" with a value of "0".*

So basically, right click on the library in SMC, select the 'Extended Properties' tab and enter the AssignMode=0 value:

[image]

Again, the credentials will last for a single session.

**However** - there is a far easier, and more robust approach (that will also work in BI Dashboard).  Just set up an appropriate authentication domain in the relevant connection (Server Manager plugin, SMC) and allow the users to update their OWN passwords using the [SAS Personal Login Manager](http://platformadmin.com/blogs/paul/2010/11/sas-personal-login-manager/) (also available in Enterprise Guide).  Simples!